# How to bind modem device to network interface

Tags: networking, serial, raspbian-lite, modem

I have a Huaweii modem connected to a raspi zero w running on a Raspbian stretch lite, on the standart Raspbian wheezie, this modem was shown in ifconfig output as usb0, but now on stretch lite there are just lo and wlan0.
How can I bind the devices ttyUSB0 - ttyUSB5 over which I can communicate via AT with the modem to a network interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer myself! I don't really know why, but somehow usb-modeswitch caused some problems, just removing the packages usb-modeswitch and usb-modeswitch-data solved the problem, now the network interface usb0 is shown properly in ifconfig output!